# Upgradation of centos/redhat from 5.x to 6.x

Tags: linux-kernel

Trying to upgrade Linux Centos/Redhat from 5.x to 6.x version without formatting the os,

need to know any steps for the upgrade from 5.x to 6.x

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-upgrading), you can simply run the flowing command to upgrade distribution and kernel:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
# arch
x86_64
# yum upgrade -y
```